# Problems saving a document copy into SharePoint directory

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

my macro creates a copy of certain pages in a document. I then want to save those pages into a SharePoint directory,  but receive

> Run-time error '13 "Type mismatch".

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I know my link is correct. Is my path wrong? My intent was for the active doc to save via path to SharePoint. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub CopyPages()
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim rCurrent As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iEnd As Integer
    Set rCurrent = Selection.Range

    ' Get page numbers to be copied
    sTemp = InputBox("Page range to copy (use format 6-7)", "")
    i = InStr(sTemp, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        iStart = Val(Left(sTemp, i - 1))
        iEnd = Val(Mid(sTemp, i + 1))

        If iStart < 1 Then iStart = 1
        If iEnd < iStart Then iEnd = iStart
        With ActiveDocument.Range
            If iStart > .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
                iStart = .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
            End If
            If iEnd > .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
                iEnd = .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
            End If
        End With

        ' Set the range
        Set rCopy = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, _
          Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=iStart)

        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, _
          Count:=iEnd
        rCopy.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End

        ' Copy range to a new document
        rCopy.Copy
        Documents.Add
        ActiveDocument.Range.PasteSpecial
        'Selecting a location where you want your selection to save
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs Path = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/pm/xxx/TSCR%20Home%20Pages%20PM%20Documentation/Portal%20Designer"
        rCurrent.Select
    Else
        If sTemp > "" Then
            MsgBox "There is no dash character"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure you cant just "save your file to the internet" like that... but let's see what others say about it

Comment: `Path :=`    Named arguments need `:=` not `=`